# What design patterns exist for large dataset manipulation within MVC for a rich client data grid?

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, data-structures, data, gui-design

I want to feed an HTML5 data grid with large data sets that the client will want to manipulate in different ways, e.g. aggregation, grouping, pivoting.

The data comes from different web services and the client will be carrying out transactional operations on it.

The data grid will contain various controls for manipulating the data and will fire off requests to the server for many of them when it can't do it itself.

I envisage some sort of flattened data structure cached in the MVC layer which maintains different views on the same data. It would feed out the requested data through a pagination control to the data grid.

Presumably this has been done before in many places. Is there a design pattern to follow? Is there an open-source implementation?

Comment: I'm quite happy with down-voting as long as it's associated with a comment, even just a couple of words. This is all about knowledge anyway, right? So if down-voters don't give a reason, no-one is going to know why. If they can't be bothered to do that, I don't see why they bother at all.

Comment: The answers posted so far are atrocious, which is what I expected.  I understood what you were asking ("has someone created a grid with these features in a well-engineered way?"), but the answerers clearly did not.  They understood it as an `icanhazpatternz` question, and they reached into their Gang of Four book to answer it.  For what it's worth, 3rd party companies like Telerik have built grids just like this.  It's a non-trivial task to do well.

Answer (score -1):

- I prefer using Repository Design pattern with large application, you can create repo classes that responsible for fetch data from Web Services and cached it with anyway you prefer.
- I prefer using abstract Factory For Web Services and its configuration Classes which will give me extensibility to switch to new service or upgrade configurations.
- also i will implement all my repos, services and configurations classes with Interfaces and inject them with IoC pattern in my web application.